# Symfony 2 Persist a JQueryFileUpload file in a Sonata Media

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

I am trying to persist a file uploaded by `JqueryFileUpload` in a Sonata Media but it is not working.
I use OneUpUploaderBundle to integrate JQueryFileUpload with Symfony2

I have already tried with `postUploadEvent` and `preUploadEvent`

And with data.files from jQuery script.

If anyone knows how to get a File Object with content inside Symfony or via JQuery would be a great help.

```
public function onUpload(PreUploadEvent $event) {

    $request = $event->getRequest();

    $files = $request->files->get('uploadFiles');

    foreach ($request->files->get('uploadFiles') as $fotoTemporaria) {

    $foto = new Media();

    $foto->setProviderName('sonata.media.provider.image');
    $foto->setContext('default');
    $foto->setBinaryContent($fotoTemporaria);
    $foto->setEnabled(true);

    $mediaManager->persist($foto);
    $mediaManager->flush();

    }

    $response = $event->getResponse();

    $response['uploadedFiles'] = $files;

    $response['success'] = true;
    return $response;
}
```

services.yml file

```
media_upload_listener:
     class: AppBundle\ClassServices\UploadListener
     arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
     tags:
         - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: oneup_uploader.post_persist, method: onUpload }
```

And jQuery file

```
$(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            add: function (e, data) {
                if (data.files && data.files[0]) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        $('#uploaded').append("<div id='imageNumber' class='imageContainer'><img class='imagePreview' src='" + e.target.result + "'> \n\
                <input type='file' name='realMedia[]' style='display:none' value='" + e.target.result + "'></div>");
                    }
                    data.result = data.files[0];
                    reader.readAsDataURL(data.files[0]);
                    data.submit();
                }
            },
            progress: function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('#progress .bar').css(
                        'width',
                        progress + '%'
                        );
            },
            done: function (e, data) {
                var out ='';
                var obj = data;
                for (var i in obj) {
                    out += i + ": " + obj[i] + "\n";
                }

                this attribute is empty
                alert(data.files);

              }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you might misunderstand sending files as XHR request with master submit of parent form.

Comment: Yes. It is because i need to program a gallery like facebook. Need to upload and image, preview it and publish in a gallery. And i am using SonataMediaBundle, OneUpUploaderBundle and JqueryFileUpload.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered what was happening. It was because i was using ObjectManager in the construct not EntityManager.

class UploadListener {

```
protected $em;

public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
    $this->em = $em;
}

public function getEm() {
    return $this->em;
}

public function onUpload(PostPersistEvent $event) {

    $file = $event->getFile();

    $entityManager = $this->getEm();

    $foto = new Media();

    $foto->setProviderName('sonata.media.provider.image');
    $foto->setContext('default');
    $foto->setBinaryContent($file);
    $foto->setUsuario($event->getRequest()->get('user'));
    $foto->setEnabled(true);

    $entityManager->persist($foto);
    $entityManager->flush();

    $response = $event->getResponse();

    $response['success'] = true;

    return $response;
}
```

}